# JS functions with different parameters communicating results

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure if this is possible and can't wrap my head around it. I have a larger project where I want to combine a couple of callbacks in different files into one and simply get the data from the different functions. My issue is that I can't seem to fetch the last part which I'll demonstrate in the code.

File one, importing file three and calling the sendUpdate function with 'note' as param.

```
const three = require("./three")
const note = "test"
three.sendUpdate(note);
```

File two,

```
async function getUser(user) {
  return await otherfileFarAway.otherFunctionFarAway(user);
}

module.exports = {
    getUser
}
```

File three, where I want to bundle these two up. I'm importing file two

```
const two = require("two");

async function sendUpdate(note) {
  const total = await two.getUser(user);
  console.log(note); // Works
  console.log(total); // Undefined, duuh

  try {
    const url
      .concat(total)
      .concat("/Notes");
    const result = await axios.post(
      url,
      {
        Comment: note
      },
    );
    return result.data;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.axiosError(error);
    return null;
  }
}


module.exports = {
    sendUpdate
}
```

How would I actually just call getUser in file two from file three and get the value it is getting in file two? Is that possible? If I call it without parameters I get nothing, if I send it with something I get undefined. If I define it beforehand with for example "let user;" I get nothing.

What am I doing wrong or is it just simply not possible to get the returned value?

Comment: Did you mean that file one actually imports file three, not file two? Please show the complete code, including the `require` statement in that file one, and also the export statements in the other modules.

Comment: Sounds like a typo. The parameter of your `sendUpdate` function is called `note`, but you are trying to pass a `user` variable to the `getUser` call.

Comment: The fact that they're from separate files shouldn't make a difference. Calling an `async` function with `await` should return what the function returns. Where do you set the variable `user` in file three?

Comment: @Bergi A note is probably not a username, so that doesn't seem likely. But passing an undefined `user` variable is probably the problem.

Comment: What is all this supposed to be doing? You're apparently trying to send a note to a user, but which user are you sending it to?

Comment: @Bergi file one requires file three yes (sorry for the typo). File three has sendUpdate in module.exports and is working.

Comment: @Barmar exactly. The whole gist of it is that note is being sent in from different places depending on what the user is doing, logging in, updating password etc. Just a simple string. But I would like for the callback logic for getting the user (lets say user.id) in file three instead of passing it together in file one every time - because that would require some redundant code. The only thing that changes over time is "note".

In file three I want them "merged", simply put. But user is undefined.

Comment: @mtorn But where should it be getting the user from? Where is the "current user" (or whatever) stored, which entity knows about it?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using Node? If that is that case you need to use `exports` to make them available via `require`. [Here's some doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

Comment: Yes, Node. I am using exports and requiring them.

Answer (score 0):

Modify `file two` to the following to add some debug messages, so you'll see what's wrong:

```
async function getUser(user) {
  console.log(`====== executing getUser() in filetwo with param: `, user);
  const result = await otherfileFarAway.otherFunctionFarAway(user);
  console.log(`====== returning `, result);
  return result;
}

module.exports = {
    getUser
}
```

Your questions seems to be *How would I actually just call getUser in file two from file three and get the value it is getting in file two?*.

The answer is that you're already calling that `filetwo.getUser(...)` properly, because **otherwise you'd get a syntax error**. It's probably that you're not sending the right parameter to it, so `otherFunctionFarAway(...)` returns `nothing`/`undefined`/`null`.

**Edit**

After your comment regarding overriding the `user` var in filetwo, a solution would be, something along the lines:

1. create and export another function in filetwo which will export the *correct* user variable
2. in `sendUpdate(...)`, before calling the present `getUser(note)` function, make another call to the above function
3. call `getUser()` with the result from point 2.

Comment: First log (user) shows the id, correct.
Second log (result) shows an array with information depending on parameter "user". 

Everything works from there. But in file three I can't seem to just access the result.

Comment: so you're saying that between the `return result;` in `getUser()` and `console.log(total)` in `sendUpdate()`, the returned value disappears somehow? are you sure you're looking at the correct log messages? add some differentiating extra strings to each `console.log()` so you're sure interpreting the right messages.

Comment: Yes. I guess it might be because in file two param user has a value set to it when it runs, but in file three nothing is. So by calling two.getUser with param (user) it overrides the existing value and sets it to.. nothing. While running getUser(user) in file two (its original place) works like a charm.

Comment: I've edited my answer in the light of your latest comment.